# how to show another div on form submit without refreshing page

Tags: forms, submit

this is a very basic one
 i have a form in html
    in which i want following functionality
    1. **when user click submit button then the mail goes and a thank you message appear in same place without refreshing the page**

here is my html
in which there are two div which is show text and get text on body load i am showing get text div and on submit i have to show next div but this not happening i dont know eher i am doing wrong

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<STYLE></STYLE>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<TITLE></TITLE>
<META content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv=content-type>
</head>
<body style="margin:0; padding:0;">

<div style=" width:311px; height:576px; background:url(img/bg.png) no-repeat; position:relative; ">
<div class="getText">
  <form action="" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="name" value="" style="width:207px; height:26px; border:1px solid black; position:absolute; top:235px; left:47px;   "/>
    <input type="text" name="email" value="" style="width:207px; height:26px; border:1px solid black; position:absolute; top:286px; left:47px;  "/>
    <input type="text" name="" value="" style="width:207px; height:26px; border:1px solid black; position:absolute; top:337px; left:47px;   "/>
    <textarea cols="23" rows="4" style="border:1px solid black; position:absolute; top:387px; left:47px;"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" style="width:76px; height:27px; border:0; outline:none; color:#ffffff; background-color:#ff0000; font-weight:bold; cursor:pointer; font-size:14px; font-family:verdana; position:absolute; top:470px; left:49px;" id="sub">
  </form>
</div>
<div class="showText" style="width:247px; height:282px; background-color:#ffac00; color;#292a2a; text-align:center; font-weight:bold; font-size:14px; font-family:verdana; position:absolute; top:216px; left:28px;"><br><br><br>   
    Thank You !<br>
    You shall hear from us soon !!

</div>
</div>

<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".showText").hide();
      ("#sub").on("click",function( ) {
      $(".showText").show();
     $(".getText").hide();

    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

on click of submit page is getting refreshed and not showing  thank you `div` i didnt want to refresh the page

Comment: you need AJAX to submit the page

Comment: You must use ajax for change the content without refreshing whole page

Answer (score 0):

Here is something to get you started on using AJAX: http://jsfiddle.net/j8rnW/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".showText").hide();
    $("#sub").on("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: '',
            method: 'post',
            data : {}, //pass your form elements as key-value pairs
            success: function (response) {
                $(".showText").show();
                $(".getText").hide();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using ajax would help. Or you can change the input type to 'button' instead of submit. Because submit always posts the form values and refreshes the page